# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition' even after sucessfull install of module

Tags: python

I have sucessfully installed face_recogintion on my cmd but still when i try to import this module its showing the following error --> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'

i have tried many times by running and even restarting my pc

Comment: please post the code that imports the module and how to installed it

Answer (score 0):

Use the same version of Python for installing with pip and using the module. For example, if your Python executable was `python3`, you would use the command `python3 -m pip install face-recognition` to install the library, and `python3 main.py` to run your code.

You can also use a virtual environment to achieve the same thing: `venv main; source main/bin/activate`.